# How can we decrypt a password which has been encrypted first using md5 and then using sha1?

Tags: php, encryption, md5, sha1

Is it possible to decrypt a password which has been encrypted using md5 and then using sha1?

$newHPass = sha1(md5($password));

Comment: You don't decrypt MD5. Hashing is a one-way operation, meaning it cannot be decrypted. However, you could brute-force the hash to find what input(s) work for it.

Comment: You can't. That's the purpose of hash functions. They're supposed to be ONE WAY, i.e. not reversable. If you don't want to run a dictionary attack or something similar you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. `md5` and `sha1` are not encryption algorithms. They are [one way hashing functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithms) which are mainly used to verify the integrity of the input.

This means that an input which is transformed to a hash with a hash function cannot be transformed back to the original value.

Comment: Although the answer in itself is correct I would rephrase the last sentence a bit. They're can't be transformed back with traditional methods but they can be broken with a dictionary or rainbow table. So the last sentence is not wrong but not completely correct since it is possible to get the original value.